# Hibernate stops working after upgrade to 4.4.0 kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel, suspend, swap, hibernate

The title says it all.
I'm now running `Linux Desktop 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I've tried the troubleshooting [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate), and `sudo pm-hibernate` returns no output, just an error code of one.

I tried the following:

```
sudo -s
echo platform > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

but I got

```
me@Desktop:~$ sudo -s
root@Desktop:~# echo platform > /sys/power/disk
bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
root@Desktop:~# echo disk > /sys/power/state
bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

and a similar error from `uswsusp`:

```
me@Desktop:~$ sudo s2disk
s2disk: Could not open the snapshot device. Reason: Operation not permitted
```

Does anybody have more troubleshooting ideas?